# Setting up an IPv6 DHCP + DNS router - hardware?

Tags: linux, home-networking, routing, freebsd

I would like to set up a DHCP (with MAC-bound allocation to mimic static) + DNS(SEC) router at home. I'm looking for hardware and software suggestions that fit into a small enclosure, approximately large enough to house a regular home router/AP.

HW Requirements:

- Completely silent
- Small power consumption
- 2+ NICs running at gigabit speeds.
- Access-point capabilities

SW Requirements:

- Support for Open Shortest Path First or a similar interior routing protocol.
- An operating system here: http://www.sixxs.net/tools/aiccu/
- Full IPv6 stack including Teredo, 6to4 and possibly ISATAP (bonus).
- Capable for partitioning some traffic through a VPN and some traffic through the SixXS handle.
- Stable

I don't need a firewall in this thing: they are pretty evil, slow and prone to errors (NAT-reflection anybody?). I trust I can secure the systems in the network instead.

Software - FreeBSD or a linux variant? Which? I don't want cumbersome GUIs running on it nor do I want any sort of web server on it. It would be nice to be able to run some other things on it though, like an erlang server, or a VPN tunnel. The point, anyway, would be that while the operating system should be addressable, I want it to work as a NAT for IPv4 and as a DHCP + router/switch for IPv6. I'm not afraid to do things on my own, but I don't want to get stuck in a corner like I have before:

- Windows Server 2008 + HyperV + FreeBSD -> fail because HyperV doesn't relay DHCP messages properly.
- Incomplete IPv6 stacks or GUIs that overwrite manual changes to support IPv6.
- The computer dying of overheating (currently the case)

---

One idea would be to use a very small ARM processor with a linux compiled for this -- e.g. if I could get a NVIDIA Tegra system-on-a-chip up and running with a slew of NICs. This system doesn't even need cooling (draws 6W) but has a clock frequency of 1 GHz. While not fast enough for most routing tasks, it's the general direction I want to go for -> silent 'enough' hardware with no electricity bill that doesn't die of overheating. I have a switch for switching internal data streams at gigabit; that's not the router's job.

Answer (score 2):

I am running the OpenWRT / Asus 500g option.  I am not running VPN although it is supported.  SSH, IMAP, and SMTP on Submission port handle my remote needs.  I use Shorewall-lite and Shorewall6-lite to firewall my network.  Firewall reflection has not been a problem.  No default passwords to hit anyway, login failures are logged.

- My first post covers [configuring IPv6 with the 6to4 anycast](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-part-2/) address.
- My second post covers upgrading to a [fixed tunnel from Hurricane Electric](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-part-2/) (thanks).

The router also does DCHP, and DNS forwarding using DNSMasq.

I have plugged in an old USB key to provide extra storage.  Mostly I use it for temporary scripts and configuration backups.